# Sending mail attachment using Java

Tags: java, email, gmail, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email using Java and Gmail. I have stored my files on the cloud and the stored files I want to send as an attachment to my email.

It should add those files to this mail and not links of those files.

How I can send such attachments?

Comment: You must be able to pull the files down from the cloud in your code. After that, just attach them

Comment: Sample 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm

Answer (score 73):

Working code, I have used Java Mail 1.4.7 jar

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class MailProjectClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "your.mail.id@gmail.com";
    final String password = "your.password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from.mail.id@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to.mail.id@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("PFA");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        
        String file = "path of file to be attached";
        String fileName = "attachmentName";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it raise connection timeout exception

Comment: I have used your class,but it gives error like this, " 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. pa5sm839428pdb.28 - gsmtp " @NINCOMPOOP

Comment: Try adding this: `props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");`

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP : I am getting Below Exception
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
 class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
 at sendMail.SendMail4.execute(SendMail4.java:70)
 at sendMail.sel.main(sel.java:10)

Comment: It should be like ```String file = "./folder1/folder2/file.txt";``` and ```String fileName = "newFileNameOnSMPTServer.txt";```.

Comment: working still 7 years and a pandemic later, thanks a lot

Comment: It seems that *message.setContent(multipart)* just removes (as it is implied) all the content set by *message.setText*. Please correct the answer.

Answer (score 39):

For an unknow reason, the accepted answer partially works when I send email to my gmail address. I have the attachement but not the text of the email.

If you want both attachment and text try this based on the accepted answer :

```
    Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "yourHost");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "yourHostPort");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");             
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


    // Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "password");
                }
              });


    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo));
        msg.setSubject("your subject");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textBodyPart.setText("your text");

        MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart= new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachementPath); // ex : "C:\\test.pdf"
        attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(fileName); // ex : "test.pdf"

        multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);  // add the text part
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart); // add the attachement part

        msg.setContent(multipart);


        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,"Error while sending email",e);
    }
```

---

**Update :**

If you want to send a mail as an html content formated you have to do

```
    MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html");
```

So basically `setText` is for raw text and will be well display on every server email including gmail, `setContent` is more for an html template and if you content is formatted as html it will maybe also works in gmail

Comment: This modification worked for me. I was getting the attachment correctly, but not getting any email body text. With the code exactly as @amdev has, I got email with body text and the attachment. Thanks!

Comment: agree with above comment, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

Using Spring Framework , you can add many attachments :

```
package com.mkyong.common;


import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.mail.MailParseException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

public class MailMail
{
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage;

    public void setSimpleMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage) {
        this.simpleMailMessage = simpleMailMessage;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(String dear, String content) {

       MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

       try{
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

        helper.setFrom(simpleMailMessage.getFrom());
        helper.setTo(simpleMailMessage.getTo());
        helper.setSubject(simpleMailMessage.getSubject());
        helper.setText(String.format(
            simpleMailMessage.getText(), dear, content));

        FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("/home/abdennour/Documents/cv.pdf");
        helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);

         }catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new MailParseException(e);
         }
         mailSender.send(message);
         }
}
```

To know how to configure your project to deal with this code , complete reading [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-with-attachment/) .

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Here I assume my attachment is of a `PDF` type format.

Comments are made to understand it clearly.

```
public class MailAttachmentTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "test@gmail.com";
        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "tester@gmail.com";
        final String username = "tester@gmail.com";//change accordingly
        final String password = "test";//change accordingly
        // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        // Get the Session object.
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Attachment");
            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            // Now set the actual message
            messageBodyPart.setText("Please find the attachment below");
            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = "D:/test.PDF";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            // Send the complete message parts
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Email Sent Successfully !!");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you allow me, **it works fine also for multi-attachments**, the 1st above answer of NINCOMPOOP, with just a little modification like follows:

```
DataSource source,source2,source3,source4, ...;  
source = new FileDataSource(myfile);  
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
messageBodyPart.setFileName(myfile);  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

source2 = new FileDataSource(myfile2);  
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source2));  
messageBodyPart.setFileName(myfile2);  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

source3 = new FileDataSource(myfile3);  
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source3));  
messageBodyPart.setFileName(myfile3);  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

source4 = new FileDataSource(myfile4);  
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source4));  
messageBodyPart.setFileName(myfile4);  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

...

message.setContent(multipart);
```

Comment: Not to mislead: this modification attend only the additional attachments. It is clear necessary to have also the insertion of additional attachments. I put the above code in a separate bean and the Client interface in a jsp file like   ""<input name="myfile" type="file"><p>  
                <input name="myfile2" type="file"><p>  
                <input name="myfile3" type="file"><p>  
                <input name="myfile4" type="file"><p>>  ""

Answer (score 0):

To send html file I have used below code in my project.

```
final String userID = "usermail@gmail.com";
final String userPass = "userpass";
final String emailTo = "mailto@gmail.com"

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userID, userPass);
            }
        });
try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));
    message.setSubject("Hello, this is a test mail..");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    String fileName = "fileName";

    addAttachment(multipart, fileName);

    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart1.setText("No need to reply.");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

    message.setContent(multipart);

    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Email successfully sent to: " + emailTo);

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String fileName){
    DataSource source = null;
    File f = new File("filepath" +"/"+ fileName);
    if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
        source = new FileDataSource("filepath" +"/"+ fileName);
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        try {
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```