# Can I send email and add an attachment using Java in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

While running a test case, I have a try/catch mechanism and an onevent listener that produces a screenshot if an error/failure occurs.
Can I also compose and email and attach that screenshot there and send it to someone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to do with selenium here, You have to Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java) and override the attachment file with your Screenshot file.

Comment: for example there is an object Session that asks me to create a class Session. What do I put in that class?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a job for whatever is running your integration tests. Typically one runs integration tests on some kind of Continuous Integration environment, such as Jenkins. Your CI environment should support emails/notification of failing tests.

Comment: Jenkins has some primitive email notifications, but I dont know how to make it attach a certain file (the one I just created)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you are using a linux box for executing your selenium test cases, you can install mutt, a CLI mail client to send mail with attachments. Also, there is JavaMail API that you can use. [JavaMail API example](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-attachment-with-email-using-java-mail-api)

If you want to use mutt, first install mutt. Then create a file `.muttrc` in your home folder and include the following parameters for e.g:

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://your_id@domain.com@smtp.gmail.com:587"
set smtp_pass = "password"
set realname = "Foo Bar"
```

Example:

```
mutt -s "test mail" your_id@domain.com -a attachment.zip < email_body.txt
```

You need to include this command in a shell script and execute the script from a Java class using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myShellScript);`