# Base64 String as attachment

Tags: java, base64, email-attachments

I converted a PDF file into Base64 string and now i want to use this string as an email attachment in Java

```
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(ssn);
        InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        message.setFrom(fromAddress);
        InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to use base64 string to make it as attchment

Comment: Do some research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java

Comment: Thats fine but i want to convert base64 string into file

Comment: @ajaykalyanynr: why don't you want the framework to do the job? You definitely need a `MimeMultipart` object...

Comment: I am using HttpServlet through Jquery ajax to send email, and i am converting file into base64 at client side

Comment: @ajaykalyanynr: and what difference does that make? You retrieve the file via HTTP Multipart on the server-side, correct? You should describe your use case...