# How to send email of log4j logs and testng emailable report after execution to Test Scripts?

Tags: selenium, log4j, appium

I am not getting exact code for the same, please help me the solution and steps to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send email using JavaMail API with log4j log and TestNG report as attachment. I am using same way to share automation report via email. Please refer: [How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail)

and for attachment:
[Sending mail attachment using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java)

Comment: If above solution help you, please accept it as answer. So that it can be useful for other too.