# How to add attachment to my mail sender JavaMail?

Tags: java, android, email, email-attachments

i'm trying to add an attachment button to my mail sender. I'm using the libraries JavaMail Mail, activation and additionnal.
My sender is splited into 3 files :

- **MainActivity** which allow the user to set the content of the mail ith edit texts
- **SendMail** which allow me to set the sender, and the content from edit texts to the mail and send it
- **Config** which is storing informations like transmitter's address and password and the receiver's address
  Here is the code of my actual mail sender which send mail properly but without attachment.

### SendMail.java

```
package com.myapp.attch_mail;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

private Context context;

private String subject;
private String message;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


SendMail(Context context, String subject, String message){

    this.context = context;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;

}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Envoi en cours","Veuillez patienter...",false,false);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    Toast.makeText(context,"Message sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Properties props = new Properties();


    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {


                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL_SENDER, Config.PASSWORD);
                }
            });

    try {

        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL_SENDER));

        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL_RECEIVER));

        mm.setSubject(subject);

        mm.setText(message);

        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

### MainActivity.java

---

```
package  com.my_app.attach_mail;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class L3C1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


private EditText objet_siq;
private EditText corps_siq;
private EditText prenom_siq;
private EditText nom_siq;
private EditText telephone_siq;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_l3_c1);


        object = findViewById(R.id.objet_siq);
        body = findViewById(R.id.corps_siq);
        first_name= findViewById(R.id.prenom_siq);
        last_name= findViewById(R.id.nom_siq);
        phone= findViewById(R.id.telephone_siq);


        Button buttonSend = findViewById(R.id.send_mail_siq);
        Button buttonAttachment = findViewById(R.id.add_attachment_siq);


        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);

}


private void sendEmail() {

    String subject = objet_siq.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = "Nom / Prénom : " + prenom_siq.getText().toString().trim() + " " + nom_siq.getText().toString().trim() + "\n" +"Téléphone : " + telephone_siq.getText().toString().trim() + "\n" + "\n" + "Description du problème : " + "\n" + corps_siq.getText().toString().trim() + "\n" + "\n" + "Cordialement, " +  prenom_siq.getText().toString().trim() + " " +nom_siq.getText().toString().trim();


    SendMail sm_siq = new SendMail(this, subject, message);


    sm_siq.execute();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    sendEmail();

    object.setText("");
    body.setText("");
    first_name.setText("");
    last_name.setText("");
    phone.setText("");

}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending mail attachment using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java)

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about what is not working on your code  ?

Comment: @MatthieuGabin [EN] Everything is working properly but i just don't know how to add the attachment to my mail... [FR] Tout fonctionne bien je ne sais juste pas comment m'y prendre pour ajouter des pièces jointes... (je suis novice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it !
I look at the MimeMessage documentation and found the solution, you just have to change the content inside of the try (in SendMail.java) to this :

```
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();


        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);



        MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        String filename = "path to your file, exemple : /storage/path.txt" ;
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);


        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.MAIL_SENDER));

        mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
        InternetAddress(Config.MAIL_RECEIVER));

        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);

        mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);

        Transport.send(mimeMessage);
```

I also changed the names of instances I used.