# Sharing option to social media(fb, whatsapp, mail) from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am building a desktop application on image steganography project in NetBeans. After encryption of the message I like to share the encrypted message(image) directly to social media(like mail, FB).

I searched on the internet but this option is only available for Android applications but not for desktop application.

I like to know any possible ways to include share options directly from netbeans or any other alternate way.

Comment: This sounds broad because for each service you have to interact with its public API. Searching on google is a good way to start. As for email, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java) should work.