# File not downloading with file extension

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have implemented java mail with org.springframework.mail.javamail but while downloading from gmail it not downloading with file extension

below is my java code

```
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
                    public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                        message.setTo("abc@gmail.com");
                        message.setFrom("sdf@gmail.com", "hello");
                        message.setText("text", true);
                        message.setSubject("subject");
                        message.addAttachment("name", file);
                    }
                };
                try {
                    mailSender.send(preparator);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

as we can see in [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovnci.png) it showing as excel file but when we download it, its downloading as file
[please see the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBxh6.png)
please help me if any thing missing or suggest any changes required

Edited

I am Creating file as `File outputFl = new File("filepath/finaleName.xls");`

Comment: @AjayKumar i just updated my question. please check

Comment: No I meant to say, how you are downloading the file. Show us that code.

Comment: i am downloading it manually from gmail. once gmail comes with attachment. please see my first and second linked images in question

Comment: @AjayKumar or anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the correct procedure to attach a file to your email body (I guess).

You should create email attachment like below:

```
MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String attachFile = "filepath/finaleName.xls";
attachPart.attachFile(attachFile);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
```

For a full working example, you can search on Google and will find a lot of working examples relevant to your requirement. [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-attachment-with-email-using-java-mail-api) [are](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm) few [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java). Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but i have tried same for other attachment type it worked, for xls type its not working

Comment: You sure the file is xls/xlsx type and not csv etc renamed as Excel File?